# Create file on remote machine in java

Tags: java

I am using follwoing code but its not showing expected output.

```
public class FileTestOnSever {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("http://10.44.25.30:success.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            // file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This creates a folder called `http:` - except if you're using Windows, where filenames can't contain `:`, where `mkdirs` will return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TravoloPerUno is correct, the file system needs to be made available.

Saying that, SMB(?) shares should work out-of-the-box on Windows (what OS are you using?). Here's an example that worked for me:

```
// smb shared directory
new File("\\\\hostname\\c$\\workspace\\foobar1.txt").createNewFile();
// or with a mapped network drive
new File("Z:\\workspace\\foobar2.txt").createNewFile();
// or with URIs
new File(new URI("file:////hostname/c$/workspace/foobar3.txt")).createNewFile();
new File(new URI("file:///Z:/workspace/foobar4.txt")).createNewFile();
```

Use `mkdirs()` if you want directories instead of a file.

Comment: Hi @Kunal - http://bit.ly/1DOkt1u - basically it means the `C$` directory is a hidden shared folder. In this case, it's the "C" drive.

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File("http://10.44.25.30:success.txt");
```

This cannot work. The argument to this constructor is a filename, not a URL. And this URL isn't even a valid HTTP URL: the final colon should be a `/`.

There is a `File(URI)` constructor but it is specifically documented to only accept `file:` URIs.

Basically `File` does not speak HTTP. You will have to use a filename that has a meaning at the client, e.g. (for Windows) `\\\\10.44.25.30\\success.txt`.

Comment: That's also my point :).

Answer (score 0):

By 'remote', do you mean 'outside' your LAN?

If it is outside your LAN, the remote machine must have its file system made available to remote clients using protocols such as NFS and Samba. This being true, you could use your method by correcting the file path. It is dependant on the protocol being used on the remote system.

If the remote machine's file system is not shared, your alternative is to use sockets. You must have access to install the receiver socket on the remote machine.

Comment: remote means in LAN Network

Comment: is it feasible URL url = new URL("file://192.168.1.157C://tmp//myfile.txt");

Comment: You could try "\\\\192.168.1.157\\Share Folder\\tmp\\myfile.txt" or "file:////192.168.1.157/Share Folder/tmp/myfile.txt"

Answer (score -2):

You probably can't do this. `File(String pathname)` can't except `http://..` stuff. Seems like you want a `URI`, but `File(URI uri)` can only acccept an `file:URI` as parameter.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html.

Comment: He isn't using `File(URI).`

Comment: He expected to use it, isn't it? I mean he can't write `http://...` as the pathname. `http://..` seems as a URI. But `File` can only accept `file:`. That's what i mean.