# Create a Text File on window remote server using Java

Tags: java

I am using following code to create a text file on remote window server:

```
String archiveFolder=\\etld90\\DM;
new File(archiveFolder + File.separator + "done" + ".txt");
```

Its not giving any error but also not creating a file.

Comment: Your code is **not supposed** to create anything other than a new `File` object in memory that is immediately discarded.

Comment: Please suggest how to achieve.

Comment: How do you connect with this remote server, via ssh? You can take a look on this http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: Follow the link I provided.

Comment: Code is on my local PC and i have all permission on specified folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create file on remote machine in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552605/create-file-on-remote-machine-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This only creates the File object in memory

createNewFile() - "Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract path name if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist"

Here's some code demonstrating it

```
  File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
  if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
    System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
  } 
  else {
    System.out.println("File already exists.");
  }
```

Comment: I am getting error java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Does the directory you are setting exist? Also I would recommend wrapping that code block with a try-catch so you can handle that IOException.

Comment: Yes,it exists.I am just creating a new file there.

Comment: You can try to use myObj.getParentFile().mkdirs(); to create the required directory

Comment: Directory already exists.Do we need any kind of permission.